Ways to merge/join vertices?
I've got to models I'm trying to merge. I've got almost all of it connected, the problem is I have three vertices that I need to join to one and still keep quad topology
: 
I also have a similar issue here:

Does anybody know how I can merge/join theses?


Do you need the quad topology for something specific or is it just because you heard the myth that you have to keep everything all quads no matter what? Because I cannot see any issue with your geometry apart from it not being quads.

I am experiencing shading issues because of it. I intend to triangulate the mesh if that helps.

Is this for export? Does the target renderer permit custom normals?

Yes, I'm going to export the mesh to Unity. However, I'm not sure what you mean by custom normals. Could you please elaborate?

You could simplify the topology instead, and give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Or use this topology:


I'm trying to keep it under 150k tris while keeping the windows smooth and round. When I tried this (might have done something wrong), I got over a million.

How will you use your object? If this is for a video, you could use a high poly version for close-up shots, and a low-poly version for large shots?

I'm going to use it for a video game.
